# Gradle - "unable to resolve class" for spring boot managed project dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

With the following gradle file within a multi project or multi module build, (lets call it web)

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id 'org.springframework.boot'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

dependencies {
  implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.14"
  implementation(project(':persistence'))
}
```

I'm unable to resolve the class files present in the project 'persistence' and get the following error while compiling

```
unable to resolve class XXX
```

This is the gradle file of the 'persistence' module

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id 'org.springframework.boot'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

dependencies {
  implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.14"
}
```

What could be the problem?

Also, here is the settings.gradle and directory structure

```groovy
// settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
  plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
  }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

rootProject.name = 'gradle-bug'
include 'commons'
include 'persistence'
include 'security'
include 'web'
```

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: Could you please add also the settings.gradle and directory structure so we can see, how the two projects are supposed to know from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When gradle sees a "implementation" dependency on a project, it uses the jar of that dependency for compilation.

When you add the `org.springframework.boot` plugin, it by default disables the jar creation task for that module, but gradle continues to depend on that jar for its compilation, even though the classes of that module have been generated in the `build/classes` folder.

To fix this, you have to enable the jar creation by adding the following snippet to the `persistence` module

```groovy
jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: You added this in the `persistence` module only, correct?

Comment: Maybe you should not apply the springboot plugin to the `persistence` subproject at all: this `springboot` plugin should be applied only on main application project, not to libraries subprojects.

Comment: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies-dependency-management-plugin-using-in-isolation : this could be used to configure your `persistence` project

Comment: @M.Ricciuti the persistence module could be used by other modules for implementing code re-usability (which was my case)